# C# split byte array into separate chunks and get number of chunks

Tags: c#, byte

Would like to split a byte array into chunks of max 1000 bytes, and get the number of resulting chunks:

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("binarydata");
```

`buffer` is 10100 bytes in this case, so it would be 11 chunks, 10 with 1000 bytes each, and one with 100 bytes.

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. Give the problem some thought (the logic is really quite simple), write an algorithm and, when you can test the algorithm with pen and paper and get the desired result, try implementing it in code. If you have trouble with that last stage, that would be the time to post a question specific to the issue you encounter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply need to know the number of chunks, you can do the following:

```
var size = buffer.Length;
var chunkCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(size / 1000F);
```

If you also want to split the buffer into many buffers, you can create an array of arrays, like so:

```
var bufferArray = new byte[chunkCount][];
```

You can then fill this new array of arrays like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++) {
    bufferArray[i] = new byte[1000];
    for (var j = 0; j < 1000 && i * chunkCount + j < size; j++) {
        bufferArray[i][j] = buffer[i * chunkCount + j];
    }
}
```

I hope this answers your question :)

EDIT:

If you need the last internal array to be exactly the size of the remaining data, you can initialize the internal array like this instead:

```
bufferArray[i] = new byte[Math.Min(1000, size - i * 1000)];
```

EDIT2:

As pointed out by xanatos in the comments, the chunkSize can be calculated faster this way:

```
var chunkCount = (size + 999) / 1000;
```

Comment: Alternative to the division: `var size = (size + 999) / 1000`

Comment: Answering bad questions simply encourages more bad questions, thus this is a bad answer.

Comment: Note that the last chunk should be smaller than 1000 bytes.

Comment: @xanatos Fixed :)

Comment: @jmcilhinney Do you really believe so? I mean, if this person has not understood how to perform these tasks, don't you think some code will help them understand?

Comment: @QuaisaqAnderson, I agree with that but that's not what SO is for. It's not a place that people who have done no research can post "this is what I want to do, show me how". There's no specific indication that the OP doesn't understand the concepts any more than that they haven't bothered to understand the concepts and have just relied on some sucker to write their code for them so that they don't have to learn how to write it for themselves. There are sites where that sort of thing is OK. SO is not one of them.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I agree that this is a bad answer. It just creates multiple chunks but the data is not copied across to each individual chunk;

Comment: Why use vars so much instead of actual types?

Comment: Also, how do you dechunks this?

Answer (score 5):

Just out of curiousity, another version. I do think there are various points of interest. The use of the integer division but rounded up, for example (`(buffer.Length + blockSize - 1) / blockSize`), or the use of a second indexer in a `for` cycle (`j`) so that we don't have to do multiplications. And the use of `Buffer.BlockCopy`, that is normally faster than copying arrays "by hand" (with a second `for` cycle)

```
public static byte[][] BufferSplit(byte[] buffer, int blockSize)
{
    byte[][] blocks = new byte[(buffer.Length + blockSize - 1) / blockSize][];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < blocks.Length; i++, j += blockSize)
    {
        blocks[i] = new byte[Math.Min(blockSize, buffer.Length - j)];
        Array.Copy(buffer, j, blocks[i], 0, blocks[i].Length);
    }

    return blocks;
}
```

Comment: We may be able to take it even further, but it requires some restrictions. If we are allowed to return any enumerable, rather than an array, and the original buffer is never altered, we are able to return ArraySegment<byte> objects, which simply reference a portion of an array. This way we don't even have to perform the copy operation!

Comment: @QuaisaqAnderson In C# 7.2 Microsoft introduced [`Span<T>`](http://adamsitnik.com/Span/#span-is-the-solution) that should be the replacement for `ArraySegment<T>`

Comment: Array.Copy would probably be faster in this situation

Comment: @TheGeneral Have you benchmarked them? I wouldn't know... Perhaps they have the same time.

Comment: Yeah just did, for `array[100,000,000]`, ArrayCopy = 0.073ms, bufferCopy = 0.126, Quaisaq = 1.821 i was suprised, also span<T> and memory<T> slice were horrible

Comment: @On [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65183/Buffer-BlockCopy-not-as-fast-as-you-think) they say the same.

Comment: Yeah i guess they work different under the hood somehow

Comment: @TheGeneral
I just ran my own benchmark and it is completely inconsistent with yours.

Array.Copy and Buffer.CopyBlock both seem to change between 400 and 500 ms on each run. (I would not expect my computer to be able to copy 100MB of data in less than 1 ms).
Where as the ArraySegment approach takes 4 - 8 ms.
I run this test on a laptop with 1600MHz DDR3 RAM, and an i5-6300HQ (2.3 GHz) CPU.

Comment: My benchmark code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/VrY5sgEx

Comment: @TheGeneral It seems that Microsoft added a [Add a fast path for `byte[]` to `Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/3118) to solve this problem.

Comment: @xanatos intersting, I'm not sure this had made it through yet as it's stil netfx-port-consider and it's still slower in core 2 and 4.7.1 in both 64bit and 32bit for any thing larger than a coupe of Kb, very interesting though

Comment: There is a small typo - it should be buffer.Length not blocks.Length here:  blocks[i] = new byte[Math.Min(blockSize, buffer.Length - j)];  Thank you for this code - it saved me lots of time.

Comment: How would you dechunk this?

Comment: @DFSFOT Totally different question, probably already answered. Try googling for join byte array c#

Comment: its adding extra items in last element which hence when joined again will contains more elements...last item should contains the remaining items...